# Getting Error 403: disallowed_useragent on Ionic Capacitor InAppBrowser google login

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, inappbrowser, ionic6

When I try to click the google login on my App it redirect me to another page with the Error 403: disallowed_useragent.

I just add overrideUserAgent setting value "Mozilla/5.0 Google" in capacitor.config.ts but it doesn't work.

Follow capacitor.config.ts

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'br.com.app.Example',
  appName: 'Example',
  webDir: 'www',
  bundledWebRuntime: true,
  overrideUserAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 Google"
};

export default config;
```

After, I execute `ionic capacitor build android` but it doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

add this to config.xml file, worked for me

```
<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 Google" />
```

Comment: Alright, but I haven't config.xml file, only capacitor.config.ts and I set it. Any another idea?